# variable that represents all the numbers in js

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, chatbot

I need a variable that represents any number, I am building a chatbot, and a frame of the conversation is the request for a document represented in a numerical way, and for that I need this variable, which can detect that it is a number

```
if(message.body.includes(numberDocument)) {
    client.sendMessage(message.from, 'is the number of document: '+message.body);
}
```

numberDocument represents my variable number, but it doesn't work

```
var numberDocument = Number
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. It sounds like you want people to be able to say something like `!document 1234` and then have your bot look up file 1234 on the server and respond with that file's content. If so, why not check whether a message _starts_ with one of your understood commands, and then parse the sentence according to the pattern you know the rest of that command should be?

Comment: `if(/^\d+$/.test(message.body))...`

Comment: I don't think that there is a value that represents any number, however you could do a number of other things: Iterate over message.body and check each value with typeof value === "number", do a regex like /-?\d+\.?\d*/, or !Number.isNan(value)

Comment: The message I will receive will be a number, and as you saw this in an if decision, that is because before that there are other branches of the conversation and to get to that point, I have to detect that the message that will send me will include a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this with regex https://regexr.com/ for tests

```
if(message.body.match(/\d/g) {
        client.sendMessage(message.from, 'is the number of document: '+message.body);
}
```

That says if there is a number in message ..., you could also try to check if the message contains anything except a number return an error

```
if(message.body.match(/\D/g) {
        client.sendMessage('invalid number');
}
```

Comment: Neither of these work for negative or decimal numbers. \D matches - and . and \d doesn't match either. Javascript has built in checks to determine if something is a number. It would be better to advise people to use one of those.

Comment: Document #1.3 ? Document #-2, why would documents be decimals or negative numbers?

Comment: The question is trying to match all numbers, not all positive integers.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a regular expression to check if a number is in the message.

Comment: Should that be some particular regular expression or any one will work? (*Not mine downvote, just in case*)

Comment: I'm not downvoting, but please provide example code.

Comment: The message I will receive will be a number, and as you saw this in an if decision, that is because before that there are other branches of the conversation and to get to that point, I have to detect that the message that will send me will include a number